# match current record with previous and next

Tags: sql, sql-server, match, recordset

I have a database in sqlserver it has data something like below

```
Employecode  Jobcode  startTime EndTime
1001         01       10:30     15:00
1001         02       15:30     18:00
1002         01       09:00     13:00
```

It has not Auto increment id

I want to match current record with previous and next record whether its `employecode` is matching with previous or next or not matching.

I want to do this in php.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What is the current record? And which column determines the next/previous row?

Comment: What ordering characteristics does the data have? The data in your example is clearly not ordered by time...

Comment: Also what version of SQL Server? SQL2012 added some features to windowing functions that will make this easy. Can be done in previous versions, but the approach will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of SQL SERVER documentation if functions LAG() and LEAD() available to you. You can use LAG() to get value from prev. row and LEAD() from next row. Then compare it to your current row. It is always good idea to create tables and data when submitting a question. You can use SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/